# Apply a same function to each column with tidyverse and mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame

```
df <- data.frame(total=100,a=5,b=5)
```

I want to apply a same function to each columns. For example, divide all columns by dividing the first column

```
df <- df/df$total
```

However, I want to do it with mutate_all

My code is like this

```
df <- data.frame(total=100,a=5,b=5) %>% mutate_all(list(~./total))
```

Which is not giving me the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Or could use `df %>% mutate_all(~./df$total)`

Comment: Or ```df %>% 
      mutate_each(list(~./total), -total)```  ***N.B.*** exclude `-total` if you want to divide the first column by itself.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the example code is using `mutate_all` correctly and *almost* works, but the question arises because of a unique situation where the order that columns are mutated matters.

Comment: @Marius Well... yeah, while it is very similar and it's easy to find the solution based on that dupe, they are not exactly the same (you already elaborated on that). Good thing akrun already reopened the question. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

`total` is the first column in your dataframe, and in `mutate_all` it gets divided by `total` first, becoming 1. Then the other columns are just divided by 1. If `total` was the last column instead I think your syntax would work, but it might not be safe to rely on that. It's probably better to use `mutate_at` and exclude `total` to avoid this:

```
data.frame(a=5,b=5,total=100) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-total), list(~./total))
```